Получение текста из span
Есть 2 php файла ex1.php и ex2.php. В ex1.php подключен ex2.php
<?php include_once "config/print.php"; ?>
В ex1.php разметка
<span id="ITEM1" class="text"></span>

В ex2.php разметка
<span id="ITEM2" class="text">Текст</span>

Как получить текст из тега с id=ITEM2 в тег с id=ITEM1


Как получить текст из тега с id=ITEM2 в тег с id=ITEM1

Например так...


$(_ => {
  $('#ITEM1').text($('#ITEM2').text())
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="ITEM1" class="text"></span>
<span id="ITEM2" class="text">Текст</span>



